# Dicominfo not giving all metadata

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have a dicom from a GE MRI scanner and there are a few pieces of information in the header I require (namely the relative position of the scan). I tried using info = dicominfo(filename) but, for some reason, this piece of information does not show up. I know that this information is saved, however. It might be a private data, but I'm not completely sure. If anyone has any information on how to resolve this issue that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `dicomread` function instead, it should be more versatile than `dicominfo` and it reads the information files too. If this doesn't work then it means that the information you are trying to obtain is not made available by GE.

Answer (score 0):

Or use [gdcm](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmdump.html) to dump the private GE header:

```
$ gdcmdump --pdb input.dcm
```